# How to render component on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that waits for a click event from the user. I also have an `<App/>` component that I render once the DOM is loaded. When the click function fires, the function should cause another component `<Table />` to render with the prop being a variable from the function. I want to be able to rerender this Table with a new prop each time the network is clicked. I was wondering if I can get some advice for how to structure my code to achieve this? My code looks like this so far (doesn't work, but it conveys what I'm trying to do)

```
let nodes = new DataSet([])
let edges = new DataSet([])
let options = {}
nodes.add({ id:0, label:'first' })
nodes.add({ id:1, label:'second' })
let data = { nodes: nodes, edges: edges }
const container = document.getElementById('network')
const network = new Network(container, data, options) //renders canvas

network.on('click', function(properties){
  const clicked = nodes.get(properties.nodes)
  return clicked;
}

class App extends Component {
render() {
  return(
    {<Table row={somehow grab 'clicked'} />}
  )
}

//in another doc
class Table extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div> this.props.row </div>
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT: I moved the network.on function inside App and it works. However, the code was very ugly; I couldn't figure out another way to interact with the canvas rendered by VIS.js so I decided to switch to d3. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix jquery with react, which is quite the anti-pattern. Are you able to move the clickable button into your React App?

Comment: First you need to define that from where you are calling that network call. On network call you can set a state for networkCalled using this.setState({networkCalled}) and now node data. Now, you can use recently settled state networkCalled in your App component for ternary condition. Whenever state is true you can call the Table component with passing updated props node..

Comment: @Roi Sorry, I'm new to React, so I'm not sure what you mean by mixing jquery and react. The network that I'm listening to is a canvas rendered by the vis.js library so I'm not sure how I would move that inside App.

Comment: @Njain I'm not sure what you mean by setting a state for networkCalled? Do you mean a class state in App? If so, how can I set the state for App if the function is outside of the component?

Comment: I think you must be calling that network within the app, or isn't it like this? @hao

Comment: @njain The network is created outside of `<App/>`. Right now, the network.on function returns a node that was clicked inside the canvas rendered by vis.js. If I can grab the node without network.on, I could move the click function into App, but since I'm not sure how to extract data from the canvas without the properties of network, I'm not sure how I can. I've updated the code above for more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this working example as a template

```js
const Table = () => {
   const [data, setData] = React.useState(['This is inital table data']);
   return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <button 
         onClick={() => {
           setData([...data, 'When button is clicked, table data state is updated with new row data']);
         }}
      >
          Add a row
      </button>
      <table>
         <tbody>
         {data.map((rowData, index) => (
             <tr key={index}>
                 <td>{rowData}</td>
             </tr>
         ))}
         </tbody>
      </table>
      </React.Fragment>
   );
};


class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Table />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```